# Simplest way to draw an SVG path

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I tried the following tutiroal from here: http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/

```
var path = document.querySelector(".svg1");
var length = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = "none";
path.style.strokeDasharray = length;
path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
path.getBoundingClientRect();
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = "stroke-dashoffset 1s ease-out";
path.style.strokeDashoffset = 0;
```

HTML is as following:

```
<path class="svg1" 
style="fill: none; stroke: #3498db; stroke-width: 7; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin:  miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4;"
d="M247 103 A130 130 0 1 1 247 363 A130 130 0 1 1 247 103"
/>
```

The thing is when I use it in Firefox, it works. But if I go for Chrome, the animation freezes at something like 75% and instantly jumps to 100% in like 30s. I've noticed, that the animation doesn't freeze only in one case - if I use `stroke-dashoffset 530ms ease-out`, i.e. 530ms or less.

Could someone suggest a solution for that or recommend a good way to animate an svg path without tons of useless code?

Comment: To be clear, when you say "animate path", you're talking about the specific animation shown in the example?

Comment: Also, what path are you talking about? The answer is very different here is you have a complex looping path vs e.g. a timeline, which only draws in LTR.

Comment: well, yes, usually "to animate a path" means to animate path drawing, as it it shown in the example. I do not know any other way to "animate" a path, than reducing dashArray from (path length) to 0

Comment: the example forms just a circle: `d="M247 103 A130 130 0 1 1 247 363 A130 130 0 1 1 247 103"`

Comment: No, "to animate a path" might mean moving a fixed path across the screen, rotating it, etc. The "draw in" animation is pretty specific.

Comment: edited the question header, thx for the tip

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/fhpc45gL/). Can you show an example that doesn't work?

Comment: How complex is the rest of your page?  It is possible that other code or animations are slowing down the overall refresh rate, causing a jump in the animation.  Have you used the timeline in Chrome's developers tools to observe the display refresh rate and factors that might be slowing it down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS-Tricks recently wrote an article](http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) on this:

The idea is we set our SVG shape with a dashed stroke where the dash length is the length of the entire path. Then we offset each dash with that path length with an animation. ([Read the article](http://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/))

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qbdgc2nv/3/)**

```css
.svg1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 822;
  stroke-dashoffset: 822;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 822;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
  <path class="svg1" style="fill: none; stroke: #3498db; stroke-width: 7; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin:  miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4;" d="M247 103 A130 130 0 1 1 247 363 A130 130 0 1 1 247 103" />
</svg>
```

### So how do you get the length of the path?

That's also covered in the above article:

Just run the code:

```
var path = document.querySelector('.svg1');
var length = path.getTotalLength();
```