# How make svg path fill as progressing animation?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-path

Is there any solution to show the battery frame `red:fill` as progress filling without covering the `rect` ?

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#iambutton").click(function () {
     console.log("hi");
    $(".mysvg").addClass( 'me' );
   });
});
```

```css
.mysvg {
  text-align: center;
}
.mysvg svg {
  margin: auto;
}
.mysvg svg #loading-frame {
  fill: red;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 10s;
  transition: all 10s;
}
.mysvg.me svg #loading-frame {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="iambutton">Clik me to see progress</button>
<section class="mysvg">
  <svg width="110px" height="88px" viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="mysvg">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
        <rect id="Brick-4" x="77.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-3" x="56" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-2" x="34.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-1" x="13" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <path id="Rectangle-7" d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"></path>
        <path d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"
        id="loading-frame"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</section>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `stroke-dash-offset` which can be animated.

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640478/whats-the-simplest-way-to-animate-draw-an-svg-path?rq=1

Comment: @Paulie_D Actually I need to show the red color as filling from the left to right instead of filling from one point and finish to the same point like rotation

Comment: Then I'd say No, there isn't. Perhaps a gradient mask or something but that's all I can think of.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for your advise and help, do you think snap.svg should be helpful ?

Comment: That or [**Greensock**](https://greensock.com/)

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil: I think splitting your paths into top and bottom, animating dashoffset of both at same time + a different path for the extra part of the end (which gets an extra class once the transition on paths are complete) would do it. Lot of work and tricky but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: @Harry that is good point 

Comment: you can use transparency, instead of draw only the battery border and use rects for levels, let the levels as wholes in your battery and animate a rect under them to show like they're filling. Redrawing it will take a bit of time, that's why I'm just commenting )

Answer (score 2):

It would be a lot easier if you drew the shape with a single path as you could then animate a single gradient to fill it. Alternatively you can extend what I've shown below to have one gradient per element with different start times and durations. I've only done two objects, you could extend the concept to the others if you want. If you want IE support, use [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/).

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#iambutton").click(function () {
    $("#a1")[0].beginElement();
    $("#a2")[0].beginElement();
    $("#a3")[0].beginElementAt(3);
    $("#a4")[0].beginElementAt(3);
   });
});
```

```css
.mysvg {
  text-align: center;
}
.mysvg svg {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="iambutton">Clik me to see progress</button>
<section class="mysvg">
  <svg width="110px" height="88px" viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="mysvg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="g1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red">
           <animate id="a1" attributeName="offset" 
             from="0%" to="100%" dur="5s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" />
        </stop>
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EAEAEA">
           <animate id="a2" attributeName="offset" 
             from="0%" to="100%" dur="5s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" />
        </stop>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="g2">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red">
           <animate id="a3" attributeName="offset" 
             from="0%" to="100%" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" />
        </stop>
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EAEAEA">
           <animate id="a4" attributeName="offset" 
             from="0%" to="100%" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" />
        </stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
          
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
        <rect id="Brick-4"  fill="url(#g2)" x="77.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-3" x="56" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-2" x="34.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-1" x="13" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <path id="Rectangle-7" fill="url(#g1)" d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"></path>

      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</section>
```

Comment: I am using Chrome v38 (old but I am stuck with it) but progress is not seen. Are you aware of any compatibility issues other than IE?

Comment: I tested this with Firefox. I'm not aware of any Chrome issues other than their intent to require a [polyfill](https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation) at some point.

Comment: Works awesome with Firefox and so smooth :)

Comment: chrome has some issues with animation of %-values. if you change the offset animation to use fractions it all works well in chrome, too.

Comment: @Robert Longson unfrotunately the solution is not working in chrome & safari

Answer (score 1):

Changing your SVG a bit you can make it work.

Instead of using `rect` to make the battery levels, let them as "holes" in your battery, so you can animate a `rect` under it and it will look like it's filling the levels.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#iambutton").click(function () {
     console.log("hi");
    $(".mysvg").addClass( 'me' );
   });
});
```

```css
.mysvg {
  text-align: center;
}
.mysvg svg {
  margin: auto;
}
.mysvg svg #loading-frame {
  fill: red;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 10s;
  transition: all 10s;
}
.mysvg.me svg #loading-frame {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="iambutton">Clik me to see progress</button>
<section class="mysvg">
  <svg width="110px" height="88px" viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="mysvg">
<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
  <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
   <rect id="loading-frame" x="0" y="0" width="110" height="88" fill="red" />
   <path d="M0 0 h110 v88 h-110z
M77.5 10 h13.5 v68 h-13.5z
M56 10 h13.5 v68 h-13.5z
M34.5 10 h13.5 v68 h-13.5z
M13 10 h13.5 v68 h-13.5z" fill="black" />
  </g>
</g>
  </svg>
</section>
```

Wait a few seconds after the click and you will see the white area being filled by red.

Sorry by the really simple SVG, but it would take more time to redraw the whole battery, you can see more about this way of making "holes" in [How to cut a hole in an SVG rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742479/how-to-cut-a-hole-in-an-svg-rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

You can make, in a javascript file, a function like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#iambutton").clickenter code here(function () {
     console.log("hi");
    $(".mysvg").addClass( 'me' );
    document.getElementByID('mysvg').fill('red')
   });
});
```

Comment: filling should be from one side to another, not just filling background

Comment: and why u cannt use addClass in a all rect and put the background. really I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I need to fill the new color from left to right like progress bar

Comment: var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "white");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);

Comment: Get the CTX and modify , that's one way the Other tell you the later right now I do not remember

Comment: @Jota: Question is about SVG but the code provided in comments is Canvas drawing. Anyway, if you are suggesting a different approach then please [edit] the code into the answer. Comments can go unnoticed.