# Gradually fill with :hover property and two svg elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like when hovering the mouse :hover to gradually fill the heart "like" from bottom to top, for this I used svg elements, only when hovering I would like only the heart to be filled, the z-index does not work not with svg, does anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance

Here is the code HTML:

```
<div class="card__icone">
                        <svg width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 21" fill="none" class="card__icone__default" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M20.3647 1.43666C18.01 -0.752399 14.5081 -0.358649 12.3468 2.07416L11.5003 3.02573L10.6538 2.07416C8.49677 -0.358649 4.99052 -0.752399 2.63583 1.43666C-0.0626076 3.94916 -0.204405 8.45854 2.21044 11.182L10.5249 20.5476C11.062 21.1523 11.9343 21.1523 12.4714 20.5476L20.7858 11.182C23.205 8.45854 23.0632 3.94916 20.3647 1.43666Z" stroke="#101010"/>
                        </svg>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="card__icone__active" width="25" height="25">
                            <g fill="url(#paint0_linear_25368_713)">
                              <rect width="25" height="25" />
                            </g>
                            <defs>
                                <linearGradient id="paint0_linear_25368_713" x1="11.5" y1="-5.45937" x2="3.93419" y2="27.993" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                <stop stop-color="#9356DC"/>
                                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FF79DA"/>
                                </linearGradient>
                            </defs>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
```

Here is the code CSS:

```
.card__icone{
    position: relative;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    height: 23px;
    /* background-color: red; */
    z-index: 2;
}

.card__icone__default{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 3;
    /* background-color: green; */
}

.card__icone__active{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -25px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.card__icone:last-child:hover .card__icone__active{
    transform: translateY(-24px);
    cursor: pointer;
    /* top: 0; */
}
```

You can see the rendering at this address: https://ohmyfood.gregorylacroix.go.yn.fr/la-palette-du-gout.html

Thanks !

I tried with the z-index property but it didn't work and I also tried to modify the svg directly but without success. Thank you in advance

Comment: You're likely looking for `mask` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask ?

Comment: Use a gradient and adjust the stop position to fill. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214162/how-make-svg-path-fill-as-progressing-animation/33215544#33215544 for instance

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try with the mask property. On the other hand, it's a training project and I have to do it only in css but thank you for the answer

Comment: @GrégoryLACROIX use a CSS gradient and animate it with CSS keyframes then.

Answer (score -1):

You must use the fill attribute with hover

`.card__icone__default:hover { fill: red; }`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the goal is to gradually fill it from bottom to top